# Converting to lambda expression with ForEach

Tags: for-loop, lambda, foreach, java-8, java-stream

Have the following sample code (this sample code was written just to illustrate the specific problem):

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    private static List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1,3,5,7,9,11,13);

    private static Map<Integer, Integer> integerMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer number = 0;
        for (Integer integer : integerList) {
            integerMap.put(number, integer);
            number++;
        }
        System.out.println(integerMap.get(3));
    }
}
```

I would like to convert it to Lambda expression using `stream()` and `forEach()` but since I have a variable `number` which is not `final` (as required inside the lambda expression), Then this specific for loop is not suitable to be converted to lambda expression?

Comment: What's wrong with the above code?  Why does it have to be stream/forEach?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, just want to utilize the internal iterator feature of `stream()` and `forEach()` introduced in Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you’re heading at, is internal iteration, you could use

```
Map<Integer, Integer> integerMap = new HashMap<>();
integerList.forEach(i -> integerMap.put(integerMap.size(), i));
```

To support arbitrary temporary mutable state not expressible with the target map itself, you would need a mutable object holding the state, either as a helper object or you resort to implement the `Consumer` as inner class.

The stream equivalent to a stateful loop, is a `Collector`. To stay with the example with ascending key numbers, you can use

```
Map<Integer, Integer> integerMap = integerList.stream()
    .collect(HashMap::new,
             (m,i) -> m.put(m.size(),i),
             (m1,m2) -> {
                 if(m1.isEmpty()) m1.putAll(m2);
                 else if(!m2.isEmpty()) {
                     int offset = m1.size();
                     m2.forEach((k,v) -> m1.put(k+offset, v));
                 }
             });
```

where the most complex thing is the combiner function for merging partial results, which is not even used in sequential execution, but mandatory for a collector.

The `Collector` API already supports using a temporary object for holding intermediate mutable state to be converted to the final result in a last step.

E.g. using a random increment instead of one:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> integerMap = integerList.stream()
    .collect(Collector.of(() -> new Object() {
                 HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
                 int lastKey;
             },
             (tmp,i) -> tmp.map.put(
                 tmp.lastKey += ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10)+1,
                 i),
             (tmp1,tmp2) -> {
                 if(tmp1.map.isEmpty()) return tmp2;
                 if(tmp2.map.isEmpty()) return tmp1;
                 int offset = tmp1.lastKey;
                 tmp2.map.forEach((k,v) -> tmp1.map.put(k + offset, v));
                 tmp1.lastKey += tmp2.lastKey;
                 return tmp1;
             },
             tmp -> tmp.map));
```

Now the collector has a fourth function which translates from the intermediate state object to the final result.

Comment: I think this `integerList.forEach(i -> integerMap.put(integerMap.size(), i));` is more intuitive than the `IntStream` solution.

The further explanation just tells us that random variable modification in the loop is just not suitable to be expressed in Lambda since the solution is way more complicated than the problem itself :).

Comment: @user892960: indeed, unless you have a really large dataset and hope for a benefit from parallel processing, there is no advantage in converting a statefull loop into a stream. But the other message is that while it is complicated, it’s not impossible. If it is a recurring task, hiding the complexity in a collector like with the [builtin collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Collectors.html) simplifies the use site.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is in your loop you are modifying a variable, streams are not really suited for that (you could use `AtomicInteger` - but it would be too much). As such, you can iterate the indexes for keys:

```
IntStream.range(0, integerList.size())
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), integerList::get));
```

Comment: Yes this solves my specific problem in which has a deterministic pattern that the `number` increment by 1 on each iteration. if we would like to make it generic (variable change inside the for loop, may not be increment by 1 but some other random action), what is the generic way to covert it to lambda expression?

Comment: @user892960 there is no generic way; either this random action could be safely expressed in terms of documentation of streams or you pretend - making it safe (like `AtomicInteger`).

Comment: So as I understand it, it all boils down to the behavior of Lambda expression where in this case I want to utilize the internal iterator. When it comes to internal iterator, the coder is not controlling when/how it executes (as opposed by the for loop), so the coder can not steer the different states within the expression itself (for subsequent iterations) as it has to be static/final. The lambda expression is, in this case defining one single behavior for all streaming/foreach elements.